# How to remove caches on Travis CI?

Tags: docker, caching, travis-ci

I cached a docker image on travis-ci. The docker image is created from a dockerfile. Now my dockerfile changed, and I need to remove caches and rebuild the docker image. How can I remove the caches on travis-ci?

My current `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: C
services:
- docker
cache:
  directories:
  - docker_cache
before_script:
- |
  echo Now loading...
  filename=docker_cache/saved_images.tar
  if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
    echo "Got one from cache."
    docker load < "$filename"
  else
    echo "Got one from scratch";
    docker build -t $IMAGE .
    docker save -o "$filename" $IMAGE 
  fi
script:
- docker run -it ${IMAGE} /bin/bash -c "pwd"
env:
- IMAGE=test04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#clearing-caches) there are three methods:

- Using the UI: "More options" -> "Caches" on the repo's page
- Using the CLI: `travis cache --delete`
- Using the [API](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#caches): `DELETE /repos/{repository.id}/caches`

That said, Docker images are one of the examples explicitly called out as a [thing not to cache](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#things-not-to-cache):

> Large files that are quick to install but slow to download do not
> benefit from caching, as they take as long to download from the cache
> as from the original source

In your example it's not clear what's involved in the pipeline beyond that Dockerfile - even if the file itself hasn't changed, any of the things that go *into* it (base image, source code, etc.) might have. Caching the image means you may get false positives, builds that pass even though `docker build` would have failed.